# How to convert 4 column table (css) to 2 column on mobile/tablet

Tags: html, css, html-table

For my recent project I have to create a responsive table like following. I have to convert 5 column table to 2 column on small screens. I think I can do it with (complex) jQuery, but that is last option. I'm tring to find a more semantic way to do it. I'll be adding non table content to it so I have to use CSS tables. I can make it to single colimn but don't know how to do this complex conversion between small and desktop devices. I tried a lot but didn't success. I don't have option (due to some reason) to use other responsive techniques. I'm looking for someone how can suggest a way t do this. Let me know if this is not possible.

[image: table]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog post that may point you in the right direction:

[CSS Tricks Responsive Data Tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

I've used this technique before with great results. Part of table's heading structure is recreated using pseudo elements. With some tweaking to match your case, it just might work for you.

Give it a try.